# 'Post' object has no attribute 'comment_set' caused by post.comment_set.all(), what does it mean when comment_set is a foreign key?

Tags: python, django

I'm following some tutorial, but didn't get when the instructor said I should put a foreignkey from comment to post so to get the comments. Instead of comment_set, I did

```
#path = request.get_full_path()
#comments = Comment.objects.filter(path=path)
```

and now I get child comment when I shouldn't get child comment. When I do `post.comment_set.all(),` instead of above two lines, I don't any comment and this error;'Post' object has no attribute 'comment_set'
. Can someone clarify how `comments = post.comment_set.filter`
 works? here's my full code.

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyProfile)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True, blank=True, related_name="commented_post")
    text = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = CommentManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('comment_thread', kwargs={"id": self.id})

    @property 
    def get_origin(self):
        return self.path

    @property
    def get_comment(self):
        return self.text

    @property
    def is_child(self):
        if self.parent is not None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_children(self):
        if self.is_child:
            return None
        else:
            return Comment.objects.filter(parent=self)
```

and my views.py

```
#for single-post page
def post(request, slug):
        user = get_object_or_404(User,username__iexact=request.user)
        try:
            profile = MyProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
            # if it's a OneToOne field, you can do:
            # profile = request.user.myprofile
        except MyProfile.DoesNotExist:
            profile = None


        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        post.views += 1  # increment the number of views
        post.save()      # and save it

        #path = request.get_full_path()
        #comments = Comment.objects.filter(path=path)
        comments = post.comment_set.all()
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        for c in comments:
                c.get_children()

        context_dict = {
            'post' :post,
            'profile' :profile,
            'comments' : comments,
            'comment_form':comment_form
        }
        return render(request, 'main/post.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: you wrote `post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True, blank=True, related_name="commented_post")`. Which means you can get all the comments from post by doing `post.commented_post.all()`. If you don't have related_name, then it would be comment_set.all(). It is backward relations, [read here] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: @AlexanderB. ah-ha that make sense...but why am I getting an error it has no attribute comment_set?

Comment: This is the default backward relation. For example you have Class A and class B that has foreignKey to A. Than to get from instance of A its objects b, you will use `a.b_set` That means according to relationships if you have some class Entity, than it will be 'entity_set'. As you changed default name - django does not create attribute **comment_set**, but creates **commented_post**. Thats why you have 'no attribute' error.

Comment: thank you very much, that's the answer

Comment: Great! I will add the answer tomorrow, or if you want you can write it and accept it yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django supports so-called "backward relations", which is simply accessing child entities backwards from the entity object. Let's say we have next models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    #some fields

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

Then Django gives you default [function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#using-a-custom-reverse-manager) to access Comment by `post.comment_set` statement. However if you want to write related_name option in annotation of your foreign key, it will change this default comment_set to ... what you've written in the related_name option. You can read about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). That is if you wrote

```
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True, blank=True, related_name="commented_post")
```

That means you have to access you comments by

```
post.commented_post.all()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hey man can you please help me with this issue, I've been having problem with this for two days...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642076/csrf-token-gives-me-403-forbidden-and-csrf-token-gives-me-500-server-err