# {{csrf_token}} gives me 403 Forbidden and {%csrf_token%} gives me 500 Server Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I read these two are basically same thing, but each one gives me different errors I'm not sure which one to go after. I don't even know how to fix this problem. Can someone please take a look at my code,,I'm struggling with this for two days now.

my html

```
<div id='notificationsLoader'>
    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".notification-toggle").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"{% url 'get_notifications_ajax' %}",
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:"{%csrf_token%}",
      },
      success: function(data){
        $("#notificationsLoader").html('<h3>notifications</h3>');
        $(data.notifications).each(function(){
          $("notificationsLoader").append(this + "<br/>")
        })
        console.log(data.notifications);
      },
      error: function(rs, e){
        console.log(rs);
        console.log(e);
      }


    })
  })
})
</script>
```

the other html

```
 <li><a class="notification-toggle" href="#">notification</a></li>
```

and notification is from my python code

```
@login_required
def get_notifications_ajax(request):
    notification = Notification.objects.get(id=id)
    notes =[]

    for note in notifications:
        notes.append(str(note))
    data={
        "notifications":notes
        }
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

there's more to this, but I'll post just this part because I think the error(both 403 and 500) is saying my server side is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Django Project Documenation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax):

> While the above method can be used for AJAX POST requests, it has some inconveniences: you have to remember to pass the CSRF token in as
>   POST data with every POST request. For this reason, there is an
>   alternative method: on each XMLHttpRequest, set a custom X-CSRFToken
>   header to the value of the CSRF token. This is often easier, because
>   many javascript frameworks provide hooks that allow headers to be set
>   on every request.

So you can pass csrftoken value as `X-CSRFToken` header, it could be fetched from cookie ( i've added `getCookie` function for that needs). You can easily do it by setuping your ajax request with [ajaxSetup](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) before sending it, see code below:

```
// Source https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax    
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

$(".notification-toggle").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var token = getCookie('csrftoken');
  $.ajaxSetup({'headers': {'X-CSRFToken': token}});
  // $.ajax...
```

Altrnatively you can try to replace your data from:

```
data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:"{%csrf_token%}",
      },
```

to

```
data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
      },
```

Comment: oh ok, this is the first time I heard about this I'll definitely try this thank you

Comment: I get Uncaught ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined

Comment: I don't understand, I have set the cookies and correct middlewear in my settings.py

Comment: thank you but I still get ReferenceError:Cookies is not defined...I have this code now; http://dpaste.com/3J8MRTR

Comment: I'm using django 1.8, is this a problem?

Comment: no that's not a problem, code updated now there are no Cookie call, i 've replaced `Cookie` to `getCookie`, see updated answer

Comment: any idea what's causing this problem?I'm following a tutorial and stuck at this stage for awhile. the instructor seems to do it without a problem, I get this error....

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: getCookie.get is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104596/discussion-between-winixxee-and-andriy-ivaneyko).

Comment: do you mind helping me with this through a chat?I would really like to fix this problem;)??

Comment: even with the changes I get uncaught ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined and TypeError: getCookie.get is not a function

Comment: is there a chance I messed up in my python code?I thought I'm having a problem with server side