# Integrate PayPal in Django app using Paypal Python SDK

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm working on a project in which I'm using Python(3.6) & Django(1.10) and I need to implement Paypal payment method in this project. I have decided to use the official Python SDK from Paypal instead of other third-party packages.It's not only the csrf problem but it also how we can render a custom form for paypal checkout button.

Here's wwhat Ihave tried.
According to the docs as [Here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/server-side-REST-integration/).
Here's my template:

```
<form class="form">
   {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="paypal-button"></div>

    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

    <script>
      var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = '{% url 'users:payment' %}';
      var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = 'https://my-store.com/paypal/execute-payment';
      paypal.Button.render({
         env:    'sandbox', // Or 'production'

         commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button
         payment: function () {
           return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL).then(function (data) {
               return data.paymentID;
    });
 },

         onAuthorize: function (data) {
             return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, {
                    paymentID: data.paymentID,
                    payerID: data.payerID}).then(function () {                                                            
                   // The payment is complete!                                                                    

                  // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
              });
            }
      }, '#paypal-button');
   </script>
 </form>
```

**From urls.py:**

```
   url('^payment/$', views.PaymentProcess.as_view(), name='payment'),
```

**From views.py:**

```
class PaymentProcess(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        mydict = {
            'paymentID': 'PAYMENTID',
        }
        print('Getting payment request')
        return json.dumps(mydict)
```

When Paypal submits a post request to **/payment** it returns 403 Forbidden error due to `csrf_token`. How can I pass the `csrf_token` with this request.

Any resource or tutorial will be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use {% csrf\_token %} in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766354/how-to-use-csrf-token-in-javascript)

Comment: No, it’s specific to PayPal python Sdk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642076/csrf-token-gives-me-403-forbidden-and-csrf-token-gives-me-500-server-err

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can add custom headers to your post request : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/master/paypalrestsdk/api.py#L270

Given that you just have to add you csrf token to the headers : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request

And your server should give you access

Comment: How can I define csrf token in the header and send it from client to server(view)?

Comment: In a JS script in your template (must be rendered directly by Django) : `var csrf_token = {{ csrf_token }};`, then use the variable wherever you need it

Comment: @AbdulRehman I would really appreciate if you could share the solution to this in case you succeded.

Comment: Sure, I will post the answer.